# Forms: Best way to have users input social media links

Tags: forms, input-fields, validation

I have a form with various inputs where I want users to be able to list various social media links such as their facebook, instagram, and twitter accounts.  Simply providing a blank textbox seems really prone to allowing user error (and has already happened once on my application).  What is the preferred way to do this?  Simply ask for their handle and build the URL myself? Form validation to make sure the url contains `facebook.com`?

Answer (score 3):

You could have it the following way.

[image]

Using the social media platforms respective **API**s you could gain access to their account address. An example of this is illustrated below.

[image]

**Users are usually logged into their social media accounts at all times.** However, without making that an assumption, even if they don't, the APIs are such that it will prompt the user to log in first and then allow you to access their public profile.

On the UI front, if the user goes through the process of letting you access their public profile, you can change the neutral grey colors of the icons to their respective colors. Blue for facebook and twitter and so on.